# Sql Server Analysis Services growing in memory until crashes

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory-leaks, data-mining, infinite-loop

I'm using Sql Server 2008 analysis services to create/train a mining model (naive bayes classifier).

If I use purely BIDS to do it, everything works fine.

If I wrote DMX queries that I send over using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.*, the Analysis Service process goes crazy and consumes more and more memory until it dies. It's like it falls into a mad infinite loop.

My question is, how can I debug this? I found some log files in program files/microsoft sql server/msas10.mssqlserver/olap/log but it wasn't much use. I really need a deeper look into AS.

I could really use some tips as to how I can gather more data as to what AnalysisServices is doing. Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In my DMX, I had an ID field in a nested table that I changed to SKIP. That took care of it.